# A question about $R$-points of an complex reductive group.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups

I hope somebody can give me a good reference for the following:

Let $G$ be a complex reductive group $H$ be a closed subgroup. Let further $R$ be any $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. Then the canonical map 
$$G(R)/H(R)\to (G/H)(R)$$
is known to be injective but in general not surjective. See for example [1].

#### So  now my question:

Let  $Z_e:=Z(G)_e$ be the connected component of center of $G$ containing $e$, is then the canonical map
$$G(\mathbb{C}((t)))/Z_e(\mathbb{C}((t)))\to (G/Z_e)(\mathbb{C}((t))) $$
a bijection.

Or even more, does the canonical map above induce an isomorphism of ind-varietes
$$ G(\mathbb{C}( (t)))/Z_e(\mathbb{C}((t)))\cong (G/Z_e)(\mathbb{C}((t))) $$

#### Remark:

Note that if we take  $ Z$ to be the center of $G$ and $R=\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ then the map above is also surjective (this follows from the fact $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ is strict henselian, hence by SGA III every map $Spec \ \mathbb{C}[[t]]\to G/Z$ can be lifted to a map $Spec \ \mathbb{C}[[t]]\to G $)

[1] Jantzen, Jens Carsten Representations of algebraic groups. Second edition. Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, 107. American Mathematical Society

Comment: Since $\mathbf{C}$ is algebraically closed, $Z_e$ is a *split* group of multiplicative type, so $Z_e$ is a *split* torus.  Thus, for any $\mathbf{C}$-algebra $R$, the obstruction to $G(R((t)))/Z_e(R((t))) \rightarrow (G/Z_e)(R((t)))$ being bijective is a class in the etale cohomology set $H^1(R((t)),Z_e)$, which is a power of ${\rm{Pic}}(R((t)))$.  For $R$ a field or even artinian local ring, this Pic is trivial and so bijectivity holds.  Thus, you have bijectivity on infinitesimal points over $\mathbf{C}$, which probably implies an isomorphism as smooth ind-schemes, yes?

Comment: It's not clear to me which motivating examples occur for you of disconnected centers in (disconnected?) reductive groups which are not semisimple.   For a connected reductive group, its center is already connected; while for a connected semisimple group, its center is finite and might cause trouble.   A standard model for what you are looking at is GL_n, with the semisimple quotient by its center being PGL_n.   Points of the latter over various fields can get complicated compared to PSL_n.  And does the characteristic matter?  Jantzen's book deals especially with prime characteristic.
 

Comment: @Jim Humphreys: it is not generally true that the center of a connected reductive (non-ss) group is connected, so it is unclear what you meant in the first part of the second sentence of your comment. For example, if $G = {\rm{SL}}_n$ and $d|n$ with $1 \le d < n$ then the central pushout of $G$ along $\mu_d \hookrightarrow {\rm{GL}}_1$ is non-ss connected reductive with disconnected center.  (Direct product if $d = 1$.) Likewise, $G := {\rm{Spin}}_{2n}$ for $n > 2$ has center $\mu_2 \times \mu_2$ or $\mu_4$ and we can form a non-ss connected reductive central pushout along a $\mu_2$.

Comment: @ayanta: Sorry, my comment on centers was too offhand.   It wasn't immediately clear to me how natural the question is in this generality.   Certainly one can construct examples of the type you mention.     

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Hilbert's Theorem 90, every torsor for a split torus over a field is trivial.  Thus, as pranavk has commented, this should give surjectivity.

$\textbf{Edit.}$  The first answer I wrote (now changed) applied to the full center $Z$.  I did not realize that the OP is asking about the quotient by $Z_e$, the connected component of the identity.  I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Now i am a little confused, so you say the statement holds also for the full center?

Comment: @Strasser: No, the argument above does not apply to the full center.  My first answer (which was only up for a few minutes) was a counterexample for the full center $Z$ in $\textb{SL}_2$.  